# SMS-Email Gateway App

Tags: sms, email

Is there any combination of android applications which can connect to a POP3 account and:

1. transfers emails to SMS (by phone number provided in the subject of
   the email)
2. transfers SMSes to an email?

Comment: The first could be tricky, but the second is possible with [SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) (only to a Gmail account AFAIR).

Comment: I need it to connect to a POP3 server, not Gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how much reliable this is, but I found this app: [SMS Gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en)

Their description says that e-mails via POP3 can be sent via SMS, while SMS can be sent via HTTP GET request.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it. What can I do for sending automatic email with incoming SMS?

Comment: No idea about sending SMS automatically as e-mails, as I have never tried it myself. It would be good if you're able to do that with the respective app, else may be suggest the developer to try providing the functionality in the further update of the app. :)